# how to call laravel route from javascript function

Tags: javascript, laravel

My route:

```
Route::get('deleterequest/{request_id}', 'RequestController@getDeleteRequest')->name('getDeleteRequest');
```

In view, i want to click a tag to call this route
View:

```
<a onclick=" confirmDelete({{ $request->task_id }})" href="#"  ><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a>
<script type="text/javascript">


function confirmDelete(id){
    document.location.href="{!! route('getDeleteRequest', $id); !!}";
}
```

when i run the code, it show error message:

> Undefined variable: id

Answer (score 3):

I just you need to parse it and replace..

```
function confirmDelete(id){
    let url = "{{ route('getDeleteRequest', ':id') }}";
    url = url.replace(':id', id);
    document.location.href=url;
}
```

or just

```
<a onclick="confirmDelete({{route('getDeleteRequest', $request->task_id) }})" href="#"  ><span class="fa fa-trash-o"></span></a>

function confirmDelete(url){
    document.location.href=url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

goto your_project_folder\config and create file constants.php if it's not exist and then define site_path constant inside it

```
define('SITE_PATH', 'http://www.yoursite.org/');
```

- and then use like this

> window.location = SITE_PATH+'deleterequest/'+id;